# The 2 person cockpit rule - what happened?

Tags: safety, accidents, cockpit

I was recently on an EasyJet flight and was chatting with the FO during the cruise about flying Microlights and other aviation fun. When he went back to the flight deck, I noticed that the Captain had been left in there alone.

I asked the cabin crew manager about it and she explained that the 2 person cockpit rule was abolished some time ago (she couldn't remember when) and that the door is now opened via facial recognition (I did notice the FO look up at a camera to unlock the cockpit door).

I then asked her if the door could still be locked from the inside - she confirmed it can.

**So my question is - how does this prevent another Germanwings?** I asked her this question and she agreed that really... it doesn't.

Comment: Ppl have to be able to go for a dump. What else are ya gonna do?

Comment: @JohnK cabin crew in the flight deck until pilot returns

Comment: The problem was "cabin crew in the cockpit until P2 returns" had other safety/security implications

Comment: If I really want to kill everybody, all I have to do is shove the column forward on final when we are at 200 ft.  That's it, done. Absolutely nothing the other pilot can do about it.